# Solr softcommit status?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm performing softcommit from many apps, I would like to  know if softcommit has ended indexing in another app and process some metrics. 
Is there's a way to get in solrj softcommit status ?

```
//in my case : 
//softCommit =true; beans is a list of solr bean that has 2000 records.

//sending my beans to the solr server
if( !(beans==null || beans.size() == 0 )){
        server.addBeans(beans);
}           

if( softCommit==false){
        //hard commit
        UpdateResponse ur = server.commit();
}
```

the problem is exactly that I do not perform a commit and that the solr server is working in background.

Doing so how can I know the commit status?

Comment: You are sending the softcommit through solrj? Then you are getting an UpdateResponse object returned from the call. Please show your code.

Comment: responded to your question. In fact I do not call the server.commit(); code, since I'm performing a softcommit. The datas are found in core but,  I don't know when the solr core will be ready to present the datas.

Comment: I think Cheffe is right? From Solrj javadoc, server.addBeans returns a UpdateResponse, in which you can call getStatus() to get the softcommit status?

Comment: @cheffe I think `UpdateResponse` will not have any information about the commit status, the status will be that document has been submitted successfully to solr for indexing. The `soft commit` or `hard commit` will be effective, what is defined in the `solrconfig.xml`, because it not done here in the code. There is `commitWithIn` version of the `addBeans` is available but that is not used by the OP.

Comment: If I understand  well, there is no solution for this "async" status of a softcommit in solr ?